# What is a complexed-valued harmonic function?

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

In Gameline's Complex Analysis, there is an exercise:

> Show that if $h(z)$ is a *complex-valued harmonic function* (solution of Laplace's equation) such that $zh(z)$ is also harmonic, then $h(z)$ is analytic.

- What does a " *complex-valued harmonic function*" mean? (The variable $z$ is not real, I don't see how to take $\Delta f(z)$).
- Could anyone come up with a cited references for such concept also?

Comment: If $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then $f$ is harmonic when $\nabla^2 u=\nabla^2v=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From *[Explorations in Complex Analysis](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=&s5=EXPLORATIONS%20IN%20COMPLEX%20ANALYSIS&s6=&s7=&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq)*:

> A complex-valued function $f(z)=f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is harmonic if $u$ and
>   $v$ are harmonic.